# How to solve a 2nd degree differnetial equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

I am currently studying mechanical engineering and as a part of the course we have an assigenment to solve a problem with an inverted pendulum. After a while we ended up with a differential equation that we have no idea on how to solve, do you have any tips? Would it be possible to find a function for $\varphi(t)$ that fulfills the constraint?

Thanks.

$L=\frac{I+M(L+r)^2}{M(L+r)}$

assume $\lvert\varphi(t)\rvert \ll 1$

$$\varphi''(t) = \frac{-(R\Omega^2\sin(\Omega t)-g)\varphi(t)+R\Omega^2\cos(\Omega t)}{L}$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I doubt this is going to play nice, both WA and Maple give nothing already with the simpler $y''(t)+\sin(\omega t)y(t)=0$, let alone with the full expression...

Comment: Presumably you should first solve $L=\frac{I+M(L+r)^2}{M(L+r)}$ for $L$.

Comment: $Ω$ itself as the frequency of the forced vibration of the base point/fulcrum will not be small, but can it be assumed that $\varepsilon=RΩ^2$ will be small? Then you can do a perturbation expansion in powers of $\varepsilon$. See the [Mathieu equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bode%5D+Mathieu+equation+perturb*)

Comment: I pulled down my earlier comment, as I see that $\phi(t) << 1$ rather than $t$.  Sorry for my confusion.  I still suspect the offer $\phi(t)$ is small is intended to prompt simplification, so would suggest instead, the equation becomes,
\begin{align}
\phi'' &= \frac{R\Omega^2}{L} (\cos(\Omega t) - \phi(t)\sin(\Omega t)) + \frac{g}{L}\phi(t) \\
&= \frac{R\Omega^2}{L} \cos(\Omega t) + \frac{g}{L} \phi(t)
\end{align}
That may be more solvable.  You will also need to solve for $L$ at some point.  The proposal here is imperfect but perhaps justified given $\phi$ is small.

Comment: The equation for $L$ gives with easy transformations $0=I+Mr(L+r)$, which makes no sense if all constants are positive. Please describe the original model and the main steps for the derivation of the model equation.